# Incomplete Windows 10 clean install

Tags: system-restore, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I started a clean install of Windows 10 on my previously Windows 7 laptop, but my daughter turned off the computer while my back was turned. Now it is in a constant reboot cycle. Can I create a bootable USB with the Windows 10 iso? If so won't it ask me for a product key (which I don't have)? What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do an upgrade install, not a clean install, to receive a license.

Once you have done an upgrade install on a particular system you can do clean installs and skip the product key (repeatedly) and it will still activate. You just MUST do the upgrade first, this generates a license for you that is stored on MS activation servers. See this other [question](https://superuser.com/questions/946889/how-does-the-clean-installation-of-windows-10-after-the-free-upgrade-work)

So, if you performed an upgrade already you can redo a clean install, use Media creation tool for windows 10 on another system.

Otherwise, you need to reinstall Win 7, activate it, upgrade it to windows 10.