# Reinstall OS: Plurality of Upgraded Windows 10 boxes

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, reinstall

A plurality of laptops and desktops were upgraded from Windows 7 or 8 to Windows 10. Ideally, a single USB install stick is capable of [reinstalling Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4000735/windows-10-reinstall) on any of these boxes.  It would be preferable to have a single USB install stick to re-install Win-10 on any box.

MS indicates that [install media can be created and a license is needed](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

Questions:

1. Can an install USB stick created on laptop be used to install on to a desktop (e.g. machine that did not create the media stick)?
2. How is the license information 'extracted' from the PC so that it can be used later to reinstall (need to record in-advance of a crash)?

Although the [How to reinstall Windows 10 on new hard disk](https://superuser.com/questions/947232/how-to-reinstall-windows-10-on-new-hard-disk)
 explains the procedure, question one is not specifically addressed and I am unable to determine, from the article,  if I need to produce a USB stick from the target machine for reinstallation on the same machine.  While it is unlikely that a install USB is somehow 'married' to its originating box, it is not impossible. It is my hope that someone can confirm that the USB install stick works on multiple boxes ('unmarried').

Lessons learned and best-practices are always appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reinstall Windows 10 on new hard disk](https://superuser.com/questions/947232/how-to-reinstall-windows-10-on-new-hard-disk)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/946889/how-does-the-clean-installation-of-windows-10-after-the-free-upgrade-work)

Comment: @SteveChambers - That is **absolutely** not true.  The installation environment is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Can an install USB stick created on laptop be used to install on to a desktop (e.g. machine that did not create the media stick)?

This absolutely can be done.

> How is the license information 'extracted' from the PC so that it can be used later to reinstall (need to record in-advance of a crash)?

Windows 8.0, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 licenses are stored within the ACPI table.  Windows 7 licenses are printed on the COA sticker located on the device.  In the case of Windows 8.0, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 the installation environment will automatically detect the license key.  Once a Windows 7 machine has been upgraded to Windows 10, you no longer are required to enter a license key, since your device uses a digital entitlement.  The same ISO can be used to install a retail or OEM license.

> Although the How to reinstall Windows 10 on new hard disk explains the procedure, question one is not specifically addressed and I am unable to determine, from the article, if I need to produce a USB stick from the target machine for reinstallation on the same machine.

Windows installation media can be used on any machine you want.  The installation environment is generic, and not connected to any specific machine, which I confirmed in my existing answer.

> There is absolutely no difference between the version of Windows 10 you receive if you purchase Windows 10 from a retailer or accept the upgrade when prompted while running an eligible installation of Windows.
>
> It is my hope that someone can confirm that the USB install stick works on multiple boxes ('unmarried').

A Windows installation media can be used on any machine you want.