# GWXWebWindows.exe just open blank IE tab instead of installing Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, windows-10-upgrade

I need a Windows 10 machine for testing purposes, so I did this:

1. Created a new machine, installed Windows 7 Enterprise
2. Activated it with my product key
3. Lauched IE to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-upgrade
4. Clicked on the big "GET STARTED" button
5. A file called `GWXWebWindows.exe` got downloaded
6. When I execute `GWXWebWindows.exe`, a new tab opens in IE and stays blank, and nothing else happen

The URL of the blank tab is https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/software-download/windows10
Checking that link on Linux, it seems to be an ISO download site.
Why would Microsoft make me download an executable just to open an URL? Why not just a hyperlink?

More importantly, how can I fix this and actually proceed with the installation?
I downloaded the ISO, but using it to overwrite the Windows 7 would [prevent me](https://superuser.com/questions/946810/windows-7-product-key-does-not-work-on-windows-10) from getting the free upgrade, right?

[image: Windows 10 upgrade fail]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Windows 7 solved the problem.

The blank tab was problem caused by an out-of-date Internet Explorer.

Open Windows Update and perform all of the security updates. It might take several days and you will need to restart your computer a dozen times.