# Missed update of Windows 10 Insider Preview turned my computer into a pumpkin

Tags: windows-10

I missed to update Insider Preview build and now my computer is turned into a pumpkin. It doesn't boot and some certificate expired. I'm able to run recovery console but not windows. And I have updated build on another computer.

[Screenshot is in russian, but you can see the date and build number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0K3I.png)

P.S. I'm not talking about cracks or illegal stuff. I just want to update one build number to another.

Upd 1. When I try to boot I see following:
[Normal boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOWZC.jpg)
I put bootable USB flash, press F8, ENTER - nothing.

When I boot from USB flash and select 'Upgrade'

[image]

Then I encounter this screen:

[image]

When I change BIOS date. I got another BSOD and after that date is reverted:

[image]

I am having trouble with these parts:

Is there a way to set earlier date? I tried but it automatically reverts back during windows boot.

Is there a way to port an expired certificate, which one?

Is there way to perform an upgrade to the new build?

Comment: When you try to boot the system normally, what error do you get? The ideal here might be the exact Russian text as well as your best effort at an English translation. Please [edit] your post to give this information.

Comment: Download the .ISO for the current Insider Preview build install it that way.  You can also wait until November 2nd 2015, indicate you want out of Insider Preview, then that should put you to the Threshold 2 build.

Comment: You can set the BIOS date and disconnect yourself from the internet then upgrade using an .ISO but you were given more then 2 months to upgrade.  You were warned this would happen for 2 months, you were told your system would stop working, your running a build from before RTM.  Your problem is that your installation is not activated and only activated copies of Windows running Insider Preview builds are authorized to be updated.

Comment: [The following thread has everything and all solutions for your problem](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/expiration-dates-for-windows-10-insider-preview/b979fd2b-f8fc-4e6b-a023-f018a0a44127)

Comment: There's also now that you can license from a previous key - http://superuser.com/questions/946810/windows-7-product-key-does-not-work-on-windows-10/989704#989704

Comment: Ramhound, I've read that forum thread. There is no solution to my problem. I had activated windows, but there was 'your microsoft account requires attention' so build was not automatically downloaded. I updated my original post here with more pictures.

Comment: What does the error message say exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load command prompt from 'Recovery Console'

1. Unhide and remove C:\Windows\bootstat.dat (Drive letter could be different)

   ```
   attrib -s -h -r C:\Windows\bootstat.dat
   del C:\Windows\bootstat.dat
   ```
2. Set earlier date

   date, enter
3. Reboot

After that you will be able to start your locked windows normally.

Related thread: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/windows-build-9879-expired-will-not-let-me-start/42101b6f-9071-46c5-a4b6-181a7174142c